# EditText generate different than spelled numbers error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a to-do list. first click menu item (add) and alertdialog write edittext and save but I'm trying to get editable text with alarm box but i get always same number.

[number photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOndS.png)

[i write bread but same number generate photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjWAN.png)

here is a menu code

```
  R.id.add -> {
                val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_todo, null)
                AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(mDialogView).setTitle("ADD TODO").setPositiveButton("Save"){
                        dialogInterface, i ->
                    val todoTitle = R.id.et_dialog_add.toString()
                    if(todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                        val todo = Todo(todoTitle)
                        todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
```

alert dialog:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_dialog_add"
    android:hint="Buy a Bread"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
```

here is adapters:

```
 fun addTodo(todo: Todo) {
    todos.add(todo)
    notifyItemInserted(todos.size -1)
}
```

Comment: What does your `onBindViewHolder()` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
val todoTitle = R.id.et_dialog_add.toString()
```

This is not how you get the text value from an `EditText` field. You need to first use `findViewById()` to get a reference to the `EditText`, and then you can use its `text` property to get what the user entered:

```
val todoTitleView = mDialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_dialog_add)
val todoTitle = todoTitleView.text
```